# Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $A$ is unitary and $S=\{Ax:x\in H\}$. Does $S^{\perp}=\operatorname{Null}(A)$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, and  $S=\{Ax:x\in H\}$. Does $S^{\perp}=\operatorname{Null}(A)$?

What I have is if $x\in S^{\perp}$ then $x\perp A(A^*A^*Ax)$  then $(x,A^*Ax)=(Ax,Ax)=0$, so $x$ is in $\operatorname{Null}(A)$, is there a more obvious reason?

How about the other direction?

Comment: In the title you write '$A$ is *unitary*'. Are you sure about this condition? Wouldn't it mean that $A$ is invertible (with $A^{-1}=A^*$)? But then $S=H$ and $S^\perp=0$.